# How to deal with extreme but "real" data, classify as outliers or no?

Tags: outliers, normalization, skewness, standardization

I have an explanatory variable, `close`, which is the daily close price of a firm in the stock market.

The following summarizes this explanatory variable:

```
                    quote at market close
-------------------------------------------------------------
      Percentiles      Smallest
 1%          .49              0
 5%          1.5              0
10%         2.95          .0002       Obs             2261717
25%         8.84          .0013       Sum of Wgt.     2261717

50%        19.39                      Mean           44.81048
                        Largest       Std. Dev.      1510.413
75%        32.78       155411.3
90%        57.02         155431       Variance        2281348
95%        74.78         155978       Skewness       86.71337
99%       126.81         155990       Kurtosis       7583.119
```

Some graphs showing transformations (I use STATA):

[image]

As you can see, the data is very skweded. My problem is how can I deal with this issue? There is not just one firm above the 99% percentile. For example:

```
 sum close if close > 126.81

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
       close |     22615    2047.126    14968.92     126.82     155990
```

And even if I were to remove all data above the 99% percentile, why choose this as a border and not for example the 95% percentile?

Note that doing a `drop if close > 126.81` does seem to normalize the data when using a square root transformation:

[image]

But again, my approach does not seem very scientific.

Finally, are there any publications I could read that deal with the particular issue of transforming/normalizing skewed price data?

Edit: can anyone tell me why `ladder` does not return anything?

```
. ladder close

Transformation         formula               chi2(2)       P(chi2)
------------------------------------------------------------------
cubic                  close^3                    .            .
square                 close^2                    .            .
identity               close                      .            .
square root            sqrt(close)                .            .
log                    log(close)                 .            .
1/(square root)        1/sqrt(close)              .            .
inverse                1/close                    .            .
1/square               1/(close^2)                .            .
1/cubic                1/(close^3)                .            .
```

Comment: Why do you want to normalize this variable?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm running a fixed effects binary logistic regression using STATA. Shouldn't the independent variables be normalized in this case?

Comment: No, it's not necessary for your independent variables to be normally distributed.

Comment: Hmm, I may be missing some basic statistical knowledge here.. so there is not even a chance of improved model fit when the independent variables are more normally distributed in logistic regression?

Comment: Some transformations are not defined. For example, $\log(0)$. This means that ladder will have a bunch of missings in the table. Similarly, that is why the log is not one of your histograms. However, I am not sure why all the output of ladder is missing.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov as opposed to what `sumarize` returns, when I `sort close` I see that none of the prices are zero.. the lowest one is 0.005.

Comment: @Tom You might have dropped some data along the way. Does the output of `summarize, detail` *now* look like what you posted above?

Comment: You are correct, thanks and sorry for being so forgetful. Interestingly enough though, while gladder now shows the log transformation, `ladder` still doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to transform your independent variable, but none of the assumptions of logistic regression require that your independent variables be Normal, even approximately.

When dealing with prices, which are often right skewed, a useful transformation is the log.

Dropping cases over a certain value can't be recommended, unless there is some other reason to do this.

Comment: If my goal is to maximize my model's fit, should I apply a transformation here? Do you know why `gladder` is not recommending me to use log?

Comment: I've edited my original question to ask for advice on why `ladder` returns missing values only.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using logarithm to normalize the variable? Quite often such extreme peaks acquire nice bell shapes after log-transforming them.

Comment: You're right, it does. In that case three questions popup: 1) why didn't STATA recommend `log`? 2) why is the output of `ladder close` blank and most importantly 3) what are the gains of log transforming a skwewed independent variable in a binary logistic fixed effects regression?